# How to make click on png image only click on nontransparent parts

Tags: javascript, html, css

For example, say I have a png img with a circle in it

[circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umM7D.png)
If I were to apply an href to this, and then made it clickable, how could I make it so only the filled in area is clickable. I would like to do this using HTML and CSS. Other languages if necessary. Thank you.

Comment: I hope you find your answer here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31909577/click-through-transparent-image-pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31909577/click-through-transparent-image-pixel)

Comment: Looks like you'll just need the inverse of the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38487569/click-through-png-image-only-if-clicked-coordinate-is-transparent